# Trying to edit a deleted post without edit privileges displays wrong error message

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, deleted-posts

When trying to edit a deleted post (such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2/edit)) as an anonymous user, or one with less than 2k rep, you get this error:

> There is a pending suggested edit in the queue, try again in a few minutes.

Shouldn't it say "this post has been deleted", or return a 404 error? It can't be due to an actual suggested edit, because I'm pretty sure that post predates them, and I've also tried it with a couple more posts which can't all have suggested edits on them.

When the post is [also locked](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1/edit), you get an appropriate error message though:

> This post is locked; locked posts cannot be edited.

Comment: Nice catch! I would just prefer plain 404 in such case same way the [revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1/revisions) page does for <10K users..

Comment: @ShaDowWizArd we plan to change that page to a full 404, but the code needs some refactoring first.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A fix will be pushed out in the next build, > rev 2012.4.11.2198.